# Space leak in list program

Tags: performance, haskell, lazy-evaluation

I am solving some problems of Project Euler in Haskell. I wrote a program for a riddle in it and it did not work as I expected.

When I looked in the task manager when running the program I saw that it was using > 1 gigabyte of RAM on ghc. A friend of me wrote a program with the same meaning in Java and succeeded in 7 seconds.

```
import Data.List

opl = find vw $ map (\x-> fromDigits (x++[0,0,9]) ) 
        $ sequence [[1],re,[2],re,[3],re,[4],re,[5],re,[6],re,[7],re,[8],re]

vw x = hh^2 == x
    where hh = (round.sqrt.fromIntegral) x

re = [0..9]

fromDigits x = foldl1 (\n m->10*n+m) x
```

I know this program would output the number I want given enough RAM and time, but there has to be a better-performing way.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The main problem here is that sequence has a space leak.  It is defined like this:

```
sequence [] = [[]]
sequence (xs:xss) = [ y:ys | y <- xs, ys <- sequence xss ]
```

so the problem is that the list produced by the recursive call `sequence xss` is re-used for each of the elements of `xs`, so it can't be discarded until the end.  A version without the space leak is

```
myseq :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
myseq xs = go (reverse xs) []
 where
  go [] acc = [acc]
  go (xs:xss) acc = concat [ go xss (x:acc) | x <- xs ]
```

PS. the answer seems to be `Just 1229314359627783009`

**Edit** version avoiding the concat:

```
seqlists :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
seqlists xss = go (reverse xss) [] []
 where
   go []       acc rest = acc : rest
   go (xs:xss) acc rest = foldr (\y r -> go xss (y:acc) r) rest xs
```

note that both of these versions generate the results in a different order from the standard `sequence`, so while they work for this problem we can't use one as a specialised version of `sequence`.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed.
The only thing I'm still wondering is why the space leak is still there when I execute opl in ghci, and it isn't there when I compile it to an executable and run it from there.

Comment: How would I find this through profiling? I spent some time profiling with `-hy` to find out that `[]` was using most of the space; but how could I have found that `sequence` was the problem?

Comment: Without profiling, the new `sequence` allows the program to run in just under 2 minutes on a dual core, 64 bit laptop (1.3-GHz Intel U7300).

Comment: Profiling would tell you that the leak was in sequence and/or the definition of (>>=) for lists, and that the leak is composed of list cells.  Beyond that, you have to reason about how sequence on lists works to understand why it leaks.  However, note that this leak is not caused by lazy evaluation - the same function in a strict language would leak in the same way.

The leak is not inherent in sequence or the list monad, but in the combination of the two. Maybe we can specialise sequence on lists to a non-leaky version, I'll think about that.

Comment: @Simon Marlow: Actually a direct translation of this code to the strict language F# avoids the space leak, even using the first definition of sequence above (using a sequence comprehension).

The reason is that the "sequence xss" is re-evaluated each time a new y is chosen, which is exactly what you want in this case.  Is there no way in Haskell to force such re-evaluation and stick with the nice simple definition of sequence?

Comment: The definition Simon gave actually does not have a space leak when optimizations are disabled, since `sequence xss` is then recomputed for each `y` (it is in a position where it syntactically could depend on `y`).  So it's no surprise that in F# there is no space leak either, since the optimization GHC makes with `-O2` of lifting `sequence xss` out of the loop would be invalid.  But the real definition `sequence ms = foldr k (return []) ms where k m m' = do { x <- m; xs <- m'; return (x:xs) }` does share the result of the recursive call for different values of the first element.

Comment: @ReidBarton sharing the value of `sequence xss` is not really an optimisation, it is just standard lazy evaluation semantics.  You get the space leak in GHC even with optimisation turned off.

Comment: @SimonMarlow maybe you do, but I don't! This is with GHC 7.0.4. http://hpaste.org/70816

Answer (score 4):

Following on from the answer given by Simon Marlow, here's a version of sequence that avoids the space leak while otherwise working just like the original, including preserving the order.

It still uses the nice, simple list comprehension of the original sequence - the only difference is that a fake data dependency is introduced that prevents the recursive call from being shared.

```
sequenceDummy d [] = d `seq` [[]]
sequenceDummy _ (xs:xss) = [ y:ys | y <- xs, ys <- sequenceDummy (Just y) xss ]

sequenceUnshared = sequenceDummy Nothing
```

I think this is a better way of avoiding the sharing that leads to the space leak.

I'd blame the excessive sharing on the "full laziness" transformation.  Normally this does a great job of creating sharing that avoids recomputions, but sometimes recompution is very much more efficient than storing shared results.

It'd be nice if there was a more direct way to tell the compiler not to share a specific expression - the above dummy `Maybe` argument works and is efficient, but it's basically a hack that's just complicated enough that ghc can't tell that there's no real dependency.  (In a strict language you don't have these issues because you only have sharing where you explicitly bind a variable to a value.)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I think I'm wrong here - changing the type signature to :: Maybe Word64 (which would be enough bits for this problem I think) also takes forever / has a space leak, so it couldn't be the old Integer bug.

Your problem seems to be an old GHC bug (that I thought was fixed) with Integer causing a space leak.  The below code finishes in about 150 ms when compiled with -O2.

```
import Data.List
import Data.Word

main = print opl

opl :: Maybe Word32
opl = find vw $ map (\x-> fromDigits (x++[0,0,9]) ) $ sequence [[1],re,[2],re,[3],re,[4],re,[5],re,[6],re,[7],re,[8],re]

vw x = hh^2 == x
    where hh = (round.sqrt.fromIntegral) x

re = [0..9]

fromDigits x = foldl1 (\n m->10*n+m) x
```

Answer (score -2):

Since you're looking for a nineteen-digit number with those characteristics found in vw, I'd try to simplify the construction in the mapped function just say `fromDigits x*1000+9` for starters. Appending to a list is O(length-of-the-left-list), so throwing those last three digits on the end hurts the computation time a bunch.

As an aside (to you both), using the strict version of the fold (`foldl1'`) will also help.

Comment: Sorry BMeph but that isn't right.  foldl1' does nothing because -O2 catches the strictness.  Also, the *1000+9 doesn't make any measureable difference - I tested that before I posted... premature optimization is the (blah blah blah)...